# Showing that the zero vector has norm zero

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I need to show that this is a property of a norm.  I know this is supposed to be straightforward but I am somehow not seeing it.
The property is 
$$\lVert 0\rVert = 0$$

I was trying to use the fact that for norms $$ \lVert\lambda \cdot x\rVert = |\lambda|\cdot  \lVert  x\rVert $$ but it seems to be lacking any real reasoning.

**EDIT** I am using the following for the definition of a norm:

1) $||x|| > 0$ if $x\neq 0$

2) $||\lambda x|| = |\lambda|||x||$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

3) $||x+y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||$

Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: I am confused. What is your definition of a norm? In my experience, this is part of the definition of a norm.

Comment: Often this is taken to be part of the definition of a norm.

Comment: Inevitably depends on details of definition. But this is a vector space, so  if the formula you quot is part of the definition, pick $\lambda=0$, and $x$ anything, zero vector is fine but it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 7):

By a vector space result, if we pick $\lambda=0$ and $x$ any vector, then $\lambda x$ is the zero-vector.

What you want now follows from (2). With $\lambda=0$, we get the zero-vector on the left. And on the right we get $0$. For on the right we just have multiplication of reals.